# Почему не хочет подключаться js файл в wp?

Tags: wordpress

Имеются файлы, скриншот которых предоставлен снизу. Справа подключение файлов (вывел отдельным кодом), а слева вся иерархия от куда я брал файлы. Точно не хотят работать файлы main.js и fullpage.js. Не пойму почему так происходит, если поможете, буду очень признателен. ЕСЛИ МАЛО информации, то обратитесь с вопросом о большей инфе

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'hutson-jquery-3.2.1.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js', array(), '20151215', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'hutson-bootstrap.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '20151215', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'hutson-fullpage', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/fullpage.js', array(), '20151215', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'hutson-simplebox.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/simplebox.min.js', array(), '20151215', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'hutson-main-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/main.js', array(), '20151215', true );
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не хотят работать - худшее из возможных объяснений. Какая ошибка в консоли браузера? В коде страницы по ctrl+U файлы есть или нет?

Comment: нет, не отображаются

Comment: Переименуй первый параметр в wp_enqueue_script в уникальное значение и посмотри в коде, сбросив браузерное кеширование.

Comment: не понял вы хотите переименовать hutson в другое значение?

Comment: А хоть что-то, описанное в этой функции, запускается? Стили, например?

Comment: Подключённые стили работают, а все файлы js нет

Comment: У вас в теме вызывается wp_footer?

Comment: Спасибо, действительно,  не вызывался footer и скрипты не подключались

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пропиши путь '../assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' две точки это выход с папки
в отцовскую hutson.

Comment: Это не работает, т.к. get_template_directory_uri и так получает главную папку hutson и от неё уже идёшь